# sendBroadcast in a BroadcastReceiver

Tags: android

Is there anything wrong with sending a broadcast in a broadcast receiver?

Comment: context.sendBroadcast(intent);

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I don't think there is any problem with sending a broadcast again from within a BroadcastReceiver.

You can see similar example [here.](http://thinkandroid.wordpress.com/2010/02/02/custom-intents-and-broadcasting-with-receivers/)

To study more about broadcast receivers plese see [the following.](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals.html#broadlife)